# Android button having two functions

Tags: java, android

I need to have a button that is suppose to have two functions.

If I tap on it once, it will go to the next page.
If I hold down on the button, it will allow me to edit the text on the button.

The button is able to go to the next page upon tapping on it, but how do I implement the second function which allows me to change the text If I hold down the button?

Does anybody know?

java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Handler h;
    private Socket socket;
    private boolean mInSettingsMode;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.43.83";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        // living button click start
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnliving);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed(irun, 0);
            }
        });

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnbed);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed(irun2, 0);
            }
        });

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndin);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed(irun3, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    Runnable irun = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, living.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    };

    Runnable irun2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, bed.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    };

    Runnable irun3 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, din.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    };

    /*
     * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Inflate the
     * menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     * getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); return true; }
     */
    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                // new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/back1"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/btnliving"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Light Control"
 />
 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/btnbed"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Fan Control"
 />
 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/btndin"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Thermostat Control"
 />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set second function as a setOnLongClickListener  as:

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //change text here
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and first function is same setOnclickListener as:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```

check this [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private static final long MAX_CLICK_TIME = 400;
    long time = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
            long pressingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            if (pressingTime > MAX_CLICK_TIME) {
                // do  change text logic
            } else {
                // show new page logic
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you want to change the text of a button without having to wait until the user removes his finger from the button, you can use TimerTask.Code with TimerTask:

```
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private static final long MAX_CLICK_TIME = 400;
        long time = 0;
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // do  change text logic
                    }
                };
                timer.schedule(timerTask, MAX_CLICK_TIME);
            } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
                long pressingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
                if (pressingTime <= MAX_CLICK_TIME) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    // show new page logic
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I have not tested, but should work. In any case, the idea should be clear.

Comment: do not add onClickListener to button